# Opening another JFrame from a button Click Event

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My question is how do I open another `JFrame` that is already created using a button Click event, in the same package?

Comment: See The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice? for some basic tips. http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/300257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Ok, so I did this, and it still didn't work. It's definitely named correctly. It says "Non-static Method setVisible() cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: @user1991372, move it out of static context and post SSCCE to your question.

Comment: I'm still very new to Stack Overflow what will posting SSCCE do?

Comment: @user1991372 sscce.org

Answer (score 2):

Try calling:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

where `frame` is whatever your JFrame (the one you're opening) is called.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I meant this to be a general comment, not a comment to your answer.

Comment: You're fine! That is a good resource any Swing developer (if there are still any) should check out.